# ClassCastException with custom xml

Tags: android, xml, classcastexception

I am trying to make custom control for xml. but it giving following error

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException:
     com.tdsoc.android.cardzlib.ui.EventElementView cannot be cast to
     android.view.ViewGroup     at
   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:624)    at
     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)   at
     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:296)   at
    com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:279)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:318)
        at
     com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
        at
    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
        at
     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1640)
        at
     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1391)
        at
     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onXmlModelChanged(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1353)  at
     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateXmlModelChanged(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:395)
        at
    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.xmlModelChanged(CommonXmlEditor.java:328)
        at
     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor$XmlModelStateListener.modelChanged(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1610)
        at
     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.wrapEditXmlModel(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1084)
        at
     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.wrapUndoEditXmlModel(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1160)
        at
    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ActionLinkStyleRange.onClick(GraphicalEditorPart.java:2457)
        at
     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ErrorLabelListener.mouseUp(GraphicalEditorPart.java:2522)
    at
     org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:219)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)   at
     org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
        at
     org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)     at
     org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)    at
     org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)    at
     org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at
     org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
        at
     org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
        at
     org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
        at
     org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at
     org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
        at
     org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
     org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)   at
    org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)   at
    org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Comment: what is the parent class of your custom class..? Is your custom class contains the child views..?

Comment: You have an invalid cast happening. Specifically you are trying to cast EventElementView to android.view.ViewGroup and that cannot be done. Showing your code, such as the xml or the java code can allow us to pinpoint the error a bit more for you. Short of this, that is all I can tell you.